# Telemetry and Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-application-insights

I used a AuthenticationHandler in my web api project. It checkes a api key. I want to send the event with Application Insigth when the user is authenticated.

I tried to do a ITelemetryInitializer but when I try to do a request, the TelemetryInitializer is called before the AuthenticatedHandler so is not authenticated...

How I could use telemetry with the authentication ? Have I need to get the telemetry's service in my AuthenticationHandler and send the event ? Is a ITelemetryInitializer is good way ? But why the ITelemetryInitializer is called before the authentication ?

It's very not clear for me.

Comment: You should probably be better by injecting the TelemetryClient in your AuthenticationHandler. DI works normally there. Then inside your handler, after authenticating the request you can send your custom telemetry. Like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#how-can-i-track-telemetry-thats-not-automatically-collected.

Comment: With the telemetry initializer, you could still check if the request is authenticated, but that doesn't tell you exactly when it was authenticated, which might be important or not.

Comment: @jpgrassi Thank you so much for the answer. it's a way that I'm considering but I was not sure that was the good way to do and i was confused between this and telemetry initializer.

Comment: I added an answer for the sake of it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that from your use case, telemetry initializers are not ideal. They are useful if you want to, for example, add things to all requests. Like a version number or the like.

If I'm not mistaken, you can still check the request inside the initializer and check if the request is authenticated, but that doesn't make much sense, IMHO. Also, for the "order" question, here is a portion of the docs:

> If you provide a telemetry initializer, it's called whenever any of the Track*() methods are called. This includes Track() methods called by the standard telemetry modules.

So, what I would do is inject the `TelemetryClient` inside your `AuthenticationHandler`, and instrument the code there as you see fit. Could send many cases, like if the API key is invalid, or how many times the same API key was used. Just be careful to what you send to not include personally identifiable information (PII).

Like I posted in the comments, here is an example of using the `TelemetryClient` via constructor injection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#how-can-i-track-telemetry-thats-not-automatically-collected to send custom telemetry.

Comment: Thank you ! That's exactly what I do now : inject the Telemetry Client inside AuthenticationHandler and that's working fine. No one personnaly identifiable information is sent ;)